# Global fetch is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future version. npm DropBox issue

Tags: node.js, npm, dropbox

I was getting the following warning

> Global fetch is deprecated and will be unsupported in a future
>   version. Please pass fetch function as option when instantiating
>   dropbox instance: new Dropbox({fetch})

The warning was produced by the following code

```
import Dropbox  from 'dropbox'
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ accessToken: dropBoxAccessToken });
dbx.filesListFolder({path: ''})
```

There is was not a great post on this at the time of this edit so I am posting in the hopes that it can save someone some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to pass fetch in as follows:

```
var dbx = new Dropbox.Dropbox({ fetch:fetch, accessToken: dropBoxAccessToken });
```

No more warning or depreciation issues

Comment: `fetch: fetch` is passing the fetch function that the dropbox API will use. You can use window.fetch or node-fetch. This confused me at first.